# Call to undefined method Yii::createWebApplication()

Tags: php, yii

```
<?php

  define('YII_ENABLE_ERROR_HANDLER', false);
  define('YII_ENABLE_EXCEPTION_HANDLER', false);
  @ini_set("display_errors",false);
  // include Yii bootstrap file
  require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/yiiframework/Yii.php');
  $config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';
  // create a Web application instance and run
  Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

Comment: which version of yii1 are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.0.8 i.e.,latest version

Comment: You have somethings wrong the file you showed is an (incorrect) Yii1 index.php for startup .. not a valid yii2 index.php

Comment: Seems that your setup is not configurated yet. Try to setup or configure the autoloader.
```php
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');  
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');  
```
More information on [autoloading is here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-autoloading.html).

Comment: thanks mate. that worked..